# If I have the COLUMN vectors (7 -11 24), (1 3 -2), (5 -1 9) in the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ then show i) (7 -11 24) ∈ Span((1 3 -2), (5 -1 9))

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If I have the COLUMN vectors $\begin{pmatrix}7 \\-11 \\24\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 \\3\\-2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}5 \\-1 \\9\end{pmatrix}$in the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ then show

> i) $\begin{pmatrix}7 \\-11 \\24\end{pmatrix} \in$ Span$(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\3 \\-2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}5 \\-1 \\9\end{pmatrix})$

> ii) Are $(1, 3, -2)$ and  $(5, -1, 9)$ linearly independant in $\mathbb R^3$?

> iii) Consider the set $S =$ Span$((7 ,-11, 24))$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. What is the dimension of $S$?

These are **my thoughts** so far:

**i)** $\alpha(1, 3, -2) + \beta(5, -1 ,9) = (7, -11 ,24)$

$\alpha + 5\beta = 7$

$3\alpha -\beta = -11$

$-2\alpha + 9\beta = 24$

so

a + 5β = 7 adding to 5(3α-β) = -11 becomes 16α = -48 so α=-3 and β=2

checking this we have -3(1 3 2) + 2(5 -1 9) which is (7 -11 24). so it checks out that its in the span

**ii)** I thought of 2 ways to do this

WAY 1: I set up the vectors as one big matrix and then found the RREF. Since the RREF has a row of zeros, the set is linearly DEPENDENT

1 5 ---> 1 5 ----> 1 5 ---> 1 0

3 -1---> 0 -16 --> 0 1 ---> 0 1

-2 9---> 0 19 ---> 0 1 ---> 0 0

WAY 2: Find coefficients for the vector that don't equal 0 when set to zero to show linear dependence

α(1 3 -2) + β(5 -1 9) =0

2α + 13β =0 so 2α = -13β so a = -13/2β which means dependent

**iii)** isn't the dimension just 1 since its column rank is 1?

Please let me know if I'm going about these problems in the right way.

- sorry all of these are written as column vectors but I'm not sure how to express that

Comment: Please use mathjax to rewrite your question above.

Comment: Your solutions look correct

Comment: For ii): from WAY 1, your row transformations already showed that $$\alpha (1,3,−2) + \beta (5,−1,9) = \mathbf 0 \implies \alpha = \beta = 0$$, hence independent.

Answer (score 0):

(i)Here is an alternative method for question (i), which seems to me to be more in the spirit of the exercise:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 5 & 7 \\3 & -1 & -11 \\-2&9&24\end{bmatrix}\overset{C'_3=C_3-7C_1}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 &  5&  0\\3 & -1 &-11  \\-2 & 9 & 24\end{bmatrix}\overset{C'_2=C_2-5C_1}\longleftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 &0  & 0 \\3 & -16 & -32 \\-2 & 19 & 38\end{bmatrix}$

So, $C'_3=2C'_2=2(C_2-5C_1)=2C_2-10C_1$

So, $C_3-7C_1=2C_2-10C_1$

And finally $C_3=2C_2-3C_1$, as OP found.

(ii) For question (ii), it suffices to note that the two vectors are not collinear.

(iii) OP is right.